# Chrome resolves site location, but I can't use tracert nor ping

Tags: java, google-chrome, https, cmd, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to access the following site using `Java` class `HttpsUrlConnection`. But it always tells `Connect timed out`. The site is:

https://www3.bcb.gov.br/expectativas/publico/consulta/serieestatisticas/

I tried to use `tracert` and `ping`, but it doesn't works.

But I can open it normally on `Chrome` (and in `IE` too).

Please, someone have some idea?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Is there a proxy between Chrome and outside?

Comment: Thank you about your response. No, it isn't. All indicates it is using, but it isn't. When I use the site http://ping.eu/ , it works, suggesting that there is a proxy. I'm thinking that might be something related to firewall, but I can't change nothing.

Comment: ping has absolutley nothing to do with HTTP traffic. And traceroute won't help you in many cases. Better use `curl` or `wget` and/or `telnet`.

Comment: Thank you. I can't use this from my job, by I'll try at my home later. But, I think that it won't help me, because the problem is here. Anyway, thanks a lot by your response.

Comment: At home you won't be able to reproduce the problem. I suppose there is indeed some firewall and/or proxy at your work which doesn't allow your java program to connect to this site. When using Chrome, you're connecting in a different way than your Java program.

Comment: Thank you again. I tried at my home to check if was a problem with the site. But is something here. Please,  sorry my ignorance: Java uses an application layer program, it isn't? I think it's not a presentation layer one nor session layer one. I guess they are taking the same way, Java and Chrome, below application layer. Thus, I'm wondering if there is something related to the HttpsURLConnection options or methods that have to be used. Anyway, thanks a lot.